# Tries : why malloc error came

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, trie

I keep getting error when running my tries program.

> a.out:  malloc.c:2372:sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodeData
{
    char ch;                /* This structure looks like a linked list */
    struct nodeData *next;
}node;

typedef struct tries
{
    node *start[26];
}tries;

tries *makeAllNull(tries *root)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<=26;i++)
    {
        root->start[i] = NULL;
    }
   return root;
}

/* Insert the given string in to the tries */
tries *insert(tries *root,char *str,int len)
{
    int i=0;
    tries *temp;
    temp = (tries *)malloc(sizeof(tries));
    while(i<len)
    {
        int k = str[i] - 'a';
        temp->start[k] = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeData));
        temp->start[k]->ch = str[i];
        temp->start[k]->next = NULL;
        if(temp->start[k] == NULL)
        {
            root->start[k] = temp->start[k];
        }
        else{
                root->start[k]->next = temp->start[k];
            }
        i++;

    }
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    tries *root;
    root = (tries *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
    makeAllNull(root);
    char str[30];
    while(i<5)
    {
        scanf("%s",str);
        root = insert(root,str,strlen(str));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `root = (tries *)malloc(sizeof(node *));` --> `root = malloc(sizeof(*root));` , `i<=26` --> `i<26`

Comment: The `node` structure is not needed. The `trie` structure should have a member that indicates a valid end-of-word. And the other member should be an array of pointers to more `trie` structures.

Comment: The error message has no useful information other than to tell you that somehow memory has been corrupted.

Comment: `int k = str[i] - 'a';` will give you negative values sometimes. So your `root->start[k]` stuff will cause your system to crash. Debug that.

Comment: Can you get [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on your machine — is it already there?  If so, use it — it will probably spot the cause of your trouble.

Comment: thanx BLUPIXY its work fine .i do wrong so my memorry is corrupted bt its work well .thanx you ALL very Mutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if(temp->start[k] == NULL)` is almost always false after `malloc` which leads to dereference `NULL` pointer at this line

```
root->start[k]->next = temp->start[k];
```

And this corrupts the memory.

Did you mean `if(root->start[k] == NULL)` instead of `if(temp->start[k] == NULL)`?

Comment: No this error come on line     
    temp = (tries *)malloc(sizeof(tries));